# I'm unsure as to why my onclick button doesn't link up with what I type into my textbox?

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, binary

So I am fairly new to Javascript, and I am working on some code that converts decimal numbers to binary numbers. However when I run this program, I can't seem to get the output I am looking for. The best I have done was get my function to output an exact number already inside of the function, when I am instead trying to get an output that is generated from any number typed into the textbox? I'm not entirely sure where I am going wrong with this. I feel like there is something I am clearly missing, but I can't seem to grasp exactly what it is. I've been using codecademy and w3schools to gain more knowledge of JavaScript, but if anyone has any other resources that helped them when they first started programming that would be great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Convert from Decimal to Binary:</p>

<form method = "post">

<p id = "demo">

<label for="decNum"></label>
    <input name="decNum" type="text">

<button onclick="toBinary()">Enter</button>

</p>

</form>

<script>
function toBinary() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    parseInt(num,10).toString(2); 
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you need to get a value for the "num"-variable, for example using "num=document.getElementById("demo").value" before trying to parse it. Secondly if you want to print/output your result, use something like "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = parseInt(num,10).toString(2); " .. and also ID your input-field as "demo" using id="demo" inside the input-tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I would change. First off, I would keep non form elements outside of the form. The major issue is that num doesn't have a value, but to ensure it works you will also want to take the event and use event.preventDefault() to make sure it doesn't submit the form. Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Convert from Decimal to Binary:</p>
<form method="post">
  <label for="decNum"></label>
  <input id="field" name="decNum" type="text">
  <button onclick="toBinary(event)">Enter</button>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function toBinary(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = document.getElementById('field').value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    parseInt(Number(value), 10).toString(2);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was definitely a bit confused about it submitting, this works out perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `num` doesn't have a value.

Try this:

```
<p>Convert from Decimal to Binary:</p>

<form method = "post">

<p id = "demo">

<label for="decNum"></label>
    <input name="decNum" type="text" id="decNum">

<button onclick="toBinary()">Enter</button>
</p>


</form>

<script>
function toBinary() {
    var num = document.getElementById("decNum").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    parseInt(num, 10).toString(2); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that! That works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining `num`.

Grab it from the input as such:

```js
function toBinary() {
    const num = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = parseInt(Number(num),10).toString(2); 
}
```

```html
<p id = "demo"></p>
<label for="decNum"></label>
<input name="decNum" type="text" id="textInput"> 
<button onclick="toBinary()">Enter</button>
```